# How to change bluetooth device name in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, bluetooth, mobile-development

How can I set my device name for bluetooth in Flutter?
In Java, there is one plugin BluetoothAdapter which could be used to set the bluetootg device name, but in Flutter, I did not find a way to do this.
thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try [FlutterBlue](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue) which is a bluetooth plugin for Flutter. You should able to do that via that plugin. Here is an example of reading/writing a characteristic from that page just in case if link goes poof:

```
// Reads all characteristics
var characteristics = service.characteristics;
for(BluetoothCharacteristic c in characteristics) {
    List<int> value = await c.read();
    print(value);
}

// Writes to a characteristic
await c.write([0x12, 0x34])
```